Movie about an alien takeover of Earth handled through separate steps
This movie didn't quite have a straight up alien invasion. The aliens' plan of action went thusly:

First, a global EMP blast would disable most of the world's electronics.
Then, they would use their advanced technology to cause natural disasters such as earthquakes and tsunamis.
Following that, they released a deadly virus upon Earth.
After that, some aliens disguised as humans would infiltrate the world's remaining militaries and try to cause civil wars.

The movie follows a group of protagonists that discover this plot and end up killing the alien that was in charge of subverting their country. However, even though the protagonists kill the alien and destroy their outpost, this is just one outpost.
I'm pretty sure the ending was a setup to a sequel, but the movie flopped in the box office and the sequel never got made.
I remember that the poster for that movie had the words

Stage 1: Darkness
Stage 2: Disaster
Stage 3: Pandemic

On it, referencing the aliens' war plan.

This sounds like the 2016 movie The 5th Wave.  Quoting the plot summary on Wikipedia:

A colossal alien spaceship is circling Earth, guided by extraterrestrial life referred to as "the Others." Ten days later, The Others unleash their 'First Wave,' an electromagnetic pulse that disables all electrical power and communications worldwide and shuts off the engines of moving vehicles, including planes in mid-flight. The 'Second Wave' gives the Others power to manipulate the planet's geology and fault lines, causing earthquakes and megatsunamis that destroy coastal cities and islands, including Miami, London, Bangkok and New York City. In Ohio, Lake Erie floods; Cassie and her younger brother Sam escape by climbing a tree. For the 'Third Wave,' the Others modify a strain of avian influenza and spread it across the planet via birds. The population is decimated, with Cassie's mother, Lisa, one of the victims. In the 'Fourth Wave,' the Others control humans and start killing other humans.

There were a number of posters similar to what you describe (click to view larger images):
  

They lost me at "Cassie and her younger brother Sam escape [apocalyptic events] by climbing a tree".

@StephenG-HelpUkraine Given the premise of the movie, the only way for someone to survive is through highly improbable circumstances.

This movie was based off the YA novel of the same name, and was one of the unfortunate victims of people getting tired of YA dystopian movie adaptations that weren't The Hunger Games.
